# iOS - Access web service running on computer from iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, ipad

I'm trying to test my iPad app which accesses a web service currently running on my machine. How can I make it so the app can make calls to the web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to connect your iPad and your PC to the same wireless network.

Comment: They are but this still involves more things to be done I assume, since the webservice is running on my computer.

Comment: Since you said the web-service is already running on your machine, you should already know the IP and port of your running service. Provided that the port is not blocked by your router, that should be all that's required to connect from inside your network. Are you seeing some different behavior?

Comment: Yes, it's running on my machine, I'm using XAMPP to host it. I moved it to the public directory on my machine, but if I try to access it, I don't see the site bur rather the directory structure.

Comment: This is what I see when I try to access the app http://yfrog.com/j8omwp It's the same structure I have in XAMPP. Yet in XAMPP the site shows up and not the directories.

Comment: What do you get when you hit the web service from the browser of another computer on your wireless network? Do you see the directory structure as you've shown here, or do you get the web app?

Comment: The same, I managed to fix this. The thing is I'm running my app from XAMPP and when I navigated to the site within the network I hit my Mac's Apache server, which was running for some reason, I turned it off and I managed to hit my app located in XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

Every computer in your network has an unique Network IP (Usually something like "192.168.0.100"). If you know how to to connect to localhost it usually suffices to change the localhost to the network IP of the computer you're trying to access,

Answer (score 0):

If your machine is a mac, I had a similar question which was answered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35282/browsing-web-page-stored-on-local-machine). Enable web sharing on the mac and everything should be available to you.

Comment: So I'd have to add my web service to the specified personal folder there, and change the routing in my app I assume.

Comment: I think so. It's not an area I know much about as you can perhaps tell from my question.